# Is there a C compiler flag that allows case insensitivity?

Tags: c, programming-languages, c99, compiler-specific

I'm just wondering, is it possible to instruct GCC (or another compiler) that I dont want case-sensitivity in my C code?

If thats impossible, then another option would be to have a compiler-flag that throws an error when it finds two global variabeles/functions, with the same name, and different casing.

Comment: The C language standard is to be case sensitive. Why would they support this ? Why do want that ?

Comment: Before sending your code to the compiler, pass it through a filter

Comment: MSVC has case-insensitive #includes for what it's worth ...

Comment: What do you mean exactly? Would you like to be able to write, for instance , `PRINTF("\n");`, or would you just like all string comparisons in your program to be  case-insensitive?

Comment: @tux3 : it's not MSVC which has a case-insensitive #includes, it's only because your filesystem is case insensitive

Comment: I tested case insensitive C compiler once. It was horrible, and broke existing code. Stick with C compiler that respects standard.

Comment: @Garf365 The filesystem itself is not case-insensitive though. NTFS is case sensitive. It's the Windows API that is in part case-insensitive. You can try this at home, create and work with two files "A" and "a" from Linux on a NTFS partition, it'll work just fine.

Comment: @tux3 Thanks for this information, I never notice it because I don't have any NTFS partition at home

Comment: @SukkoPera I want the variabele/function names case insensitive, because my IDE (Eclipse) does always such a bad job with auto-correct. And I think its scary to have two seperate variabeles in my code with different casing.

Comment: @Muis: don't take it as an offense, but that's the silliest reason I have ever heard. IDEs should help you shape your code the way you want it to, not the other way round. If Eclipse doesn't do this, drop it, there are plenty of IDEs out there. Tried Code::Blocks? Variables with different casing are definitely scary, and you should just avoid that. You should be using a naming convention that helps in that way: if you are using plain C it's common to use the "always lowercase style with underscores", try to stick to that.

Comment: Adding to previous comment: if such a compiler did exist, indeed, you would write code that is not portable at all and you would be be forced to withstand any bugs/issues it might have. Sounds more daunting than charming to me.

Answer (score 5):

Strange question.... C is a case sensitive language, it seems to me that is impossible to find a case insensitive compiler.

A possible solution is to parse source code before and lower each caracters, and after that compile it.

**EDIT :**
According comments, I discourage to parse code to change case of caracters, causing some trouble with libraries

Comment: That won't play well with upper case standard library identifiers.

Comment: @juanchopanza : is right, and if you upper each caracters, it is with lower case standard library you'll have some trouble. So, finally it's not a good idea to parse code before